# Opposite command of "restrict y to domain"

Tags: pgfplots

How can I obtain the exact opposite of the command `restrict y to domain`? I have data in a table and I would like to color points inside [min:max] as black, and points outside [min,max] as red. I figured out how to place the black data by means of the `restrict y to domain` option, but I don't know how to do the opposite for the "red data".

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

This is what `y filter` is for (it's what `restrict y to domain` uses internally as well). Within `y filter/.code`, you have access to the current y coordinate and can run tests on it. At the end of the code, the current content of `\pgfmathresult` is used as the new y coordinate.

In your case, you can use a filter like

```
y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{y / or(y<3, y>10)}}
```

to restrict the range to points less than 5 or greater than 10. The `or(...)` statement will evaluate to zero otherwise, leading to a division by zero, which causes the points to quietly be discarded.

[image]

You can wrap this in a convenience style, of course, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 8
5 16
}\datatable

\pgfplotsset{
    ignore points in x range/.style args={#1:#2}{
        x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{x/or(x<#1, x>#2)}}
    },
    ignore points in y range/.style args={#1:#2}{
        y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{y/or(y<#1, y>#2)}}
    }
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, gray, restrict y to domain=3:10] table {\datatable};
\addplot [only marks, red, ignore points in y range=3:10] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas. The example used is borrowed from [percusse’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) currently [deleted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146294).

As you may have noticed, using something like

```
restrict y to domain=-inf:⟨lower⟩, restrict y to domain=⟨upper⟩:inf
```

is not the opposite of

```
restrict y to domain=⟨lower⟩:⟨upper⟩
```

as simply nothing is plotted at all.

As `restrict to y domain` just adds more `y filter` to the plot resulting in a logical AND of those restrictions.

---

My **first** approach is rather easy: Use two plots, one for `-inf:⟨lower⟩`, one for `⟨upper⟩:inf`.

The `forget plot` style helps to “carry” settings (in “setting cycle” or whatever that is called by PGFplots) and legend entries over to the next plot.

---

The **second** implementation just adds a simply `y filter` that tests exactly that:

```
\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult>⟨upper⟩||\pgfmathresult<⟨lower⟩?\pgfmathresult:"inf"}
```

Saved in a style `restrict y to outside` defined as

```
restrict y to outside/.style args={#1:#2}{
  unbounded coords=jump,
  y filter/.append code=%
    {\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult>#2||\pgfmathresult<#1?\pgfmathresult:"inf"}}},
```

we can use it with `restrict y to outside=1:5`.

---

Now, borrowing from percusse’s answer and exploiting the internal possibilities of the `@restrict to domain` key, the **third** approach:
The PGFPlots package already offers the keys `restrict expr to domain[*]={⟨math⟩}{⟨range⟩}` which only act on the *x* dimension. Though, it isn’t hard to implement them for the other dimension:

```
restrict y expr to domain/.style 2 args ={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={y}{#1}{#2}{0}},
restrict y expr to domain*/.style 2 args={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={y}{#1}{#2}{1}},
```

We can now use

```
restrict y expr to domain={\pgfmathresult>⟨upper⟩||\pgfmathresult<⟨upper⟩}{⟨lower⟩:⟨upper⟩}
```

Or for repeated use, we better define a style

```
exclude y to domain/.style args={#1:#2}{
  /pgfplots/restrict y expr to domain={\pgfmathresult>#2||\pgfmathresult<#1}{#1:#2}},
```

for the same effect:

```
restrict y expr to domain=⟨lower⟩:⟨upper⟩
```

(Here, you have the opportunity to adjust >, <, >=, <= as you need as these kind of filter are filtering actually `⟨lower⟩ < y ≤ ⟨upper⟩` due to their implementation.)

---

The **fourth** implementation borrows the code from the original key that installs the filters for the other cases (internally, that is `/pgfplots/@restrict to domain`) and swaps the outcomes of the conditionals. I don’t know the advantages of the second implementation, the values are probably better handled by PGF(Plots)math.

This implementation is covered by the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

### Code

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dat}
0 -4
1 -3
2 -2
3 -1
4 0
5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
9 5
10 6
11 7
12 8
13 9
14 10
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{
  restrict y to outside/.style args={#1:#2}{
    unbounded coords=jump,
    y filter/.append code=%
      {\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult>#2||\pgfmathresult<#1?\pgfmathresult:"inf"}}},
  restrict y expr to domain/.style 2 args={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={y}{#1}{#2}{0}},
  restrict y expr to domain*/.style 2 args={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={y}{#1}{#2}{1}},
  restrict z expr to domain/.style 2 args={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={z}{#1}{#2}{0}},
  restrict z expr to domain*/.style 2 args={/pgfplots/@restrict to domain={z}{#1}{#2}{1}},
  exclude y to domain/.style args={#1:#2}{
    /pgfplots/restrict y expr to domain={\pgfmathresult>#2||\pgfmathresult<#1}{#1:#2}},
}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
  Exclude x to domain/.style={/pgfplots/@exclude to domain={x}{}{#1}{0}},
  Exclude y to domain/.style={/pgfplots/@exclude to domain={y}{}{#1}{0}},
  Exclude z to domain/.style={/pgfplots/@exclude to domain={z}{}{#1}{0}},
  @exclude to domain/.code args={#1#2#3#4}{% inspired by "@restrict to domain"
      \if0#4%
        \pgfkeysalso{/pgfplots/unbounded coords=jump}%
      \fi
      % when invoked, ##1 and ##2 will be floats:
      \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb##1:##2\relax{%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
          /pgfplots/#1 filter/.append code={%
            \pgfplots@warn@if@log@basis@unset{#1}{domain restriction}%
            \let\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@orig=\pgfmathresult
            \ifx\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@empty
              % the input value is empty... skip it!
            \else
              \def\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@tmp{#2}%
              \ifx\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@tmp\pgfutil@empty
                % we don't have an expression.
              \else
                % evaluate the expression!
                \pgfmathparse{#2}%
              \fi
              \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{\pgfmathresult}%
              \let\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@tmp=\pgfmathresult
              %
              \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{if less than}
                {\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@tmp}{##1}% ##1 is the lower argument
                {%
                  \let\pgfmathresult=\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@orig
                }{%
                  \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{if less than}
                    {##2}{\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@tmp}
                    {\let\pgfmathresult=\pgfplots@restrict@to@domain@orig}
                    {\edef\pgfmathresult{\if0#4-inf\else ##2\fi}}%
                }%
            \fi
          }%
        }%
      }%
      % when invoked, ##1 and ##2 will be the user-supplied args.
      \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPc##1:##2\relax{%
        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{##1}%
        \let\pgfplots@rangea=\pgfmathresult
        \pgfplotscoordmath{default}{parsenumber}{##2}%
        \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPc{\pgfplots@rangea:\pgfmathresult}%
        \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPb\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\relax
      }%
      \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{#3}%
      \expandafter\pgfplots@loc@TMPc\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[restrict y to domain=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
  \addplot+[forget plot, restrict y to domain=-inf:.9999] file {\jobname.dat};
  \addplot+[             restrict y to domain=5.0001:inf] file {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[restrict y to domain =1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
  \addplot+[restrict y to outside=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[restrict y to domain=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
  \addplot+[ exclude y to domain=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot+[restrict y to domain=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
  \addplot+[ Exclude y to domain=1:5] file {\jobname.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]